# Unable to locate grooveUtil.dll

Tags: windows-xp

When im trying to run a programme or open a files...it sometimes will shows up an errors [Unable to Locate GrooveUtil.dll . Reinstallng might fix this problem]. But when i go to search for it...i found it inside a folder name Office12. Why will this happen and can someone told me how to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Microsoft Office Groove from your computer.

[How to uninstall Groove (KB 907504)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907504)